# Unable to import SDK into dotliquid build in Visual Studio 2017rc

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I've tried to build

https://github.com/dotliquid/dotliquid

> using visual studio 2017RC but I get the following errors from the
>   build after the project files are upgraded.
>   C:\Users\phelan\workspace\dotliquid\src\DotLiquid\DotLiquid.csproj :
>   error  : The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.props"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk. 
>   C:\Users\phelan\workspace\dotliquid\src\DotLiquid\DotLiquid.csproj
>
> C:\Users\phelan\workspace\dotliquid\src\DotLiquid.Tests\DotLiquid.Tests.csproj
>   : error  : The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.props"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk. 
>   C:\Users\phelan\workspace\dotliquid\src\DotLiquid.Tests\DotLiquid.Tests.csproj
>
> C:\Users\phelan\workspace\dotliquid\src\DotLiquid.Website\DotLiquid.Website.csproj
>   : error  : The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web\Sdk\Sdk.props"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk. 
>   C:\Users\phelan\workspace\dotliquid\src\DotLiquid.Website\DotLiquid.Website.csproj
>
> C:\Users\phelan\workspace\dotliquid\src\DotLiquid.Website.Tests\DotLiquid.Website.Tests.csproj
>   : error  : The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.props"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk. 
>   C:\Users\phelan\workspace\dotliquid\src\DotLiquid.Website.Tests\DotLiquid.Website.Tests.csproj
>
> C:\Users\phelan\workspace\dotliquid\src\DotLiquid\DotLiquid.csproj :
>   error  : The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.props"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk. 
>   C:\Users\phelan\workspace\dotliquid\src\DotLiquid\DotLiquid.csproj
>
> C:\Users\phelan\workspace\dotliquid\src\DotLiquid\DotLiquid.csproj :
>   error  : The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk\Sdk.props"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk. 
>   C:\Users\phelan\workspace\dotliquid\src\DotLiquid\DotLiquid.csproj

I have had a look in the visual studio install directory and there is no folder

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Sdks

What is up here?

Comment: FYI; My colleague hit this today upon installed VS2017 RC v15.0.26020.0 (with Installer v1.2.21220.1). My installation from a month ago is running VS2017 RC v15.0.26014.0 and didn't see this problem. Unfortunately it is difficult to be certain of the Installer version I used originally because when running it now I suspect it is self-updating as the version number is the same as my colleague (v1.2.21220.1).

We worked around it by copying the directory from my machine, that being: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Sdks\*.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comment above a colleague experienced this today and even copying across the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Sdks` didn't fully resolve the issue.

After much investigation it seems that if you don't select ".NET Core and Docker (Preview)" in the "Workloads" tab then ***even with the .NET components selected in the "Individual Components" tab*** your installation will not fully support .NET Core; this includes if you've additionally installed the .NET Core SDK manually.

We didn't have any desire to have the Docker element of the install so we choose not to tick this and instead use the "Individual Components" tab, but as said it appears not to work as expected.